# Trying to replace newline in StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to replace all NewLines in a StringBuilder with nothing, and I thought this would work...but it doesn't.

```
Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\n");
Matcher matcher2 = replace.matcher(sb);
matcher2.replaceAll("");
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Assign `matcher2.replaceAll("");` to some `String` .

Comment: you also have too many `\\` you escape for a backslash, but then have a n being looked for. So you might want to consider maybe using `\n\r` or just simply `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matcher.replaceAll("blah")` returns `String` so there is nothing about performing operation on StringBuilder. However you are not using any method of `StringBuilder` except `toString()`. `StringBuilder` are mutable but in your case you are using `Matcher` class replace the string.

Answer is just capture **replaced string** in a variable.

```
String str= matcher2.replaceAll("");
```

[Matcher.replaceAll()@Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29)

You can understand this by simple below example.

```
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("I love JAVA");
    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("love");
    Matcher matcher2 = replace.matcher(sb.toString());
    String s=matcher2.replaceAll("hate");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(s);
```

**Prints**:

```
   I love JAVA
   I hate JAVA
```

`Sb` has not been changed yet.

Comment: Since [`Pattern#matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) takes any [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) as parameter, you don't need to call `sb.toString()` in `replace.matcher(sb)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String message = matcher2.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` are immutable so

```
matcher2.replaceAll("");
```

will return a new `String` without altering the `StringBuilder`. Just use the result

```
String result = matcher2.replaceAll("");
```